# I have written a JavaScript Function for iterating Object Properties and is not Working Properly

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, object, javascript-objects

I have written a ***function to iterate through an object*** and is not working properly someone please help me and tell me where am I making a mistake in my function here is What I tried:

```
//Function Checking online User
let countOnline = (usersObj) => {
  let onlineUsers = 0;
  for (let user in usersObj) {
    if (user.online === true) {
      onlineUsers += 1;
    }

  }
  return onlineUsers;
}
//Sample Object
let obj1 = {
  Alan: {
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    online: false
  }
}
console.log(countOnline(obj1));
```

Comment: @Bergi oops yea you're right, deleting *e* I must need more coffee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use usersObj[user] to access the online variable of the user:

```js
//Function Checking online User
let countOnline = (usersObj) => {
  let onlineUsers = 0;

  for (let user in usersObj) {

   console.log(usersObj[user].online);

    if (usersObj[user].online) {
      onlineUsers += 1;
    }       

  }
  return onlineUsers;
}

//Sample Object
let obj1 = {
  Alan: {
    online: false
  },
  Jeff: {
    online: true
  },
  Sarah: {
    online: false
  }
}
console.log(countOnline(obj1));
```